# python use join for unicode to str

Tags: python, list, unicode

my code like this

```
import os,sys,re,string,types

cved = [
    u'Python\u662fPython\u8f6f\u4ef6\u57fa\u91d1\u4f1a\u7684\u4e00\u5957\u5f00\u6e90\u7684\u3001\u9762\u5411\u5bf9\u8c61\u7684\u7a0b\u5e8f\u8bbe\u8ba1\u8bed\u8a00\u3002\u8be5\u8bed\u8a00\u5177\u6709\u53ef\u6269\u5c55\u3001\u652f\u6301\u6a21\u5757\u548c\u5305\u3001\u652f\u6301\u591a\u79cd\u5e73\u53f0\u7b49\u7279\u70b9\u3002\r',
    u'Python\u7684Modules/socketmodule.c\u6587\u4ef6\u4e2d\u7684\u2018socket.recvfrom_into\u2019\u51fd\u6570\u5b58\u5728\u7f13\u51b2\u533a\u6ea2\u51fa\u6f0f\u6d1e\u3002\u8fdc\u7a0b\u653b\u51fb\u8005\u53ef\u501f\u52a9\u7279\u5236\u7684\u5b57\u7b26\u4e32\u5229\u7528\u8be5\u6f0f\u6d1e\u6267\u884c\u4efb\u610f\u4ee3\u7801\u3002\u4ee5\u4e0b\u7248\u672c\u53d7\u5230\u5f71\u54cd\uff1aPython 2.7.7\u4e4b\u524d\u76842.5\u7248\u672c\uff0c3.3.4\u4e4b\u524d\u76843.x\u7248\u672c\uff0c3.4rc1\u4e4b\u524d\u76843.4.x\u7248\u672c\u3002', u'\u76ee\u524d\u5382\u5546\u5df2\u7ecf\u53d1\u5e03\u4e86\u5347\u7ea7\u8865\u4e01\u4ee5\u4fee\u590d\u6b64\u5b89\u5168\u95ee\u9898\uff0c\u8865\u4e01\u83b7\u53d6\u94fe\u63a5\uff1a\r'
]

print "".join(cved)
```

why is the first unicode value not printed?

The output is:

```
Python的Modules/socketmodule.c文件中的‘socket.recvfrom_into’函数存在缓冲区溢出漏洞。远程攻击者可借助特制的字符串利用该漏洞执行任意代码。以下版本受到影响：Python 2.7.7之前的2.5版本，3.3.4之前的3.x版本，3.4rc1之前的3.4.x版本。目前厂商已经发布了升级补丁以修复此安全问题，补丁获取链接：
```

Where did the `Python是Python软件基金会的一套开源的、面向对象的程序设计语言。该语言具有可扩展、支持模块和包、支持多种平台等特点` text go?

Comment: Don't use `\r` at the end then.

Comment: expected output it prints well for me

Comment: @VigneshKalai: no, in a terminal you only get the second value, because the first was overwritten after the `\r` sends the cursor back to the start of the line.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes,first unicode has '\r',but how i can replace this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks code ninja you rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string includes `\r` carriage return values, causing the first element to be *overwritten* by the second. The carriage return causes the terminal to move the cursor to the start of the line and any subsequent characters overwrite what was printed first.

Strip those `\r` characters first:

```
print u"".join([s.rstrip('\r') for s in cved])
```

I used [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove those characters from the end; if you have the same characters in the middle of your text, you could use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead:

```
print u"".join([s.translate({13: None}) for s in cved])
```